# ArgumentException when adding row to grid with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a simple Grid on a WinForms app called dgAttributes. I use the following code to set up the columns:

```
dgAttributes.Columns.Clear();
dgAttributes.Columns.Add("Path", "Path");
dgAttributes.Columns.Add("Parameter", "Parameter");
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
        HeaderText = "DataConnection",
        Name = "DataConnection",
        DisplayMember = "ConnectionName",
        ValueMember = "ServerName",
        DataSource = _dataConnections
};
dgAttributes.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
dgAttributes.Columns.Add("Tag", "Tag");
```

The _dataConnections variable contains a list of DataConnections and is always populated with at least one valid instance. I want the ConnectionName to be displayed in the Grid.
The DataConnection class looks like this:

```
public class DataConnection
{
    public string ServerName;
    public string UserName;
    public string ConnectionName;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ConnectionName;
    }
}
```

But when I try to do the following:

```
DataConnection conn = _dataConnections.DefaultIfEmpty(_dataConnections.FirstOrDefault())
                        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ConnectionName == point.DataConnection);
dgAttributes.Rows.Add(point.RelativePath, point.Element.Name, conn, point.Tag);
```

I get an ArgumentException (without InnerException) on the second line stating:

> Field called ConnectionName does not exist.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think it's something very obvious but I really can't seem to figure it out. And I did look at examples and other posts but it looks like I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the information from MSDN should be taken very literally:

> then the DisplayMember property must be set to the necessary property
>   name or column name.

Where "property" is the keyword here. Fields will not work. Thus after changing the string fields to properties, all was well.
I must say that the Exception message is pretty missleading. And I hope this saves someone, somewhere, some head scratching.

(source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Head scratching saved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, Setting DatagridView's "AutoSizeColumnsMode" value to "All cells" will give this error and setting the value back to "None" solved the problem